# How do I return or console.log my function to return my array of choice?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, return, console.log

I am practicing my JavaScript and I am just trying to make a simple rock paper scissors game, I followed a little guide, but when I console.log it, it just prints the function not the array of choices. How do I get those choices?

```
let choice = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors'];

function computerPlay () {
    return choice[Math.floor(Math.random * choice.length)];
}

console.log(computerPlay);
```

Comment: Add () to make a function call. Logging the name alone will log the function. console.log(computerPlay());

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make 2 changes for your code to run

1. Change *Math.random* to `Math.random()`
2. Change *console.log(computerPlay)* to `console.log(computerPlay())`

> You need to call a function using **fn_name()** to execute it.

```js
let choice = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors'];

function computerPlay() {
  return choice[Math.floor(Math.random() * choice.length)];
}

console.log(computerPlay());
```

Comment: Thank you works fine now, So if i just wana call this, i can put computerPlay(); right?

Comment: yep, just remember *function_name()*